# WinAPI create PatternBrush with offset

Tags: c++, winapi

Sorry for the unclear title, but I'm having a problem with WinAPI.

I have created a window and added double buffering for graphics, and now I'm trying to draw a rectangle using `FillRect()`. The only problem is when I'm using `CreatePatternBrush()` to texture the rectangle, the texture then always starts at `(0, 0)` no matter where the rectangle starts.

I would like to, for example, be able to draw a rectangle between `(10, 10)` and `(60, 60)` and have the texture's corners match the rectangle's corners. Is that possible or do I have to use `BitBlt()` instead?

Comment: Feels like code that you actually wrote and code that you describe are different.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-setbrushorgex